# $V$ has an orthonormal basis.

Tags: inner-products, orthonormal

Let $V$ be a finite dimensional inner product space. Then $V$ has an orthonormal basis.

My approach: We will use induction on the dimension on $V$.
This is trivial if $\dim(V)=1$, as in this case take any $x≠0$ on $V$, then $\{x/\Vert x \Vert\}$ is an orthonormal basis of $V$. So let $\dim(V)>1$ and suppose that we have the desired result for all smaller dimensions. Take any proper subspace $U$ of $V$. Then $0<\dim(U)<\dim(V)$. So, $U^⊥$ is also a proper subspace of $V$. Then by induction conditions both $U$ and $U^⊥$ have orthonormal basis say $A$ and $B$ respectively. Now I have to prove $A \cup B$ is an orthonormal basis of $V$.

How I will show this? Please help me .

Comment: Have you heard of Gram-Schmidt?

Comment: To continue your approach, do you know that $V$ splits as the direct sum of $U$ and $U^⊥$?

Comment: @James. Yah I know Gram-Schmidt, but I want to proceed in this way.

Comment: It is easy to show that $A \cup B$ is an orthonormal set of vectors; the last thing you need to show is that it spans $V$. As James has hinted, this will boil down to showing that any vector in $V$ can be written as a sum of a vector from $U$ with a vector from $U^\perp$. The usual way one proves this last result is using Gram-Schmidt, so I am not sure it is avoidable. Perhaps I am missing some slicker way to answer your question without Gram-Schmidt.